# prefix commands linux c++ application

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I have a C++ application in linux. I run it `application arg1 arg2`
When I run `ps -eaf` I see it with the paramters.

The problem is when I run it with prefix flag:  `PREFIX_FLAG application arg1, arg2`
When I run `ps -eaf` I see only `application arg1 arg2` but without the **PREFIX_FLAG**.

How can I get it (**using ps**) from the terminal the **PREFIX_FLAG also**?

played with flag except e, a ,f to see the full command that was given to terminal

Comment: You cannot see the full command that was given to terminal using ps. It is not stored anywhere.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked (it's impossible to get the exact command), but "-E" flag shows the environment at process creation, which in your case would include this "PREFIX_FLAG".